# T-SQL Query XML Data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have the following formatted XML:

```
<ROOT>
 <table1>
  <row ID="1".... \>
 </table1>
 <table2>
  <row ID="1".... \>
 </table2>
...
</ROOT>
```

I would like to produce a query that returns:

```
TableName
table1
table2 
...
```

In other words, the value of each node under

Comment: Sorry, the desired output did not format properly. Basically I just want a list of all values (table1, table2, etc.) under the ROOT node.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

```
 DECLARE @data XML;

SET @data = 

N'
<root>
 <table1>
  <row ID="1"/>
 </table1>
 <table2>
  <row ID="1"/>
 </table2>
</root>';


SELECT
    T.myAlias.value('fn:local-name(..)', 'nvarchar(50)') as ParentOf_RowElement_Name
FROM 
    @data.nodes('//row') AS T(myAlias)

;



ParentOf_RowElement_Name
--------------------------------------------------
table1
table2
```

OR

```
DECLARE @data XML;

SET @data = 

N'
<root>
 <table1>
  <row ID="1"/>
 </table1>
 <table2>
  <row ID="1"/>
 </table2>
</root>';


SELECT
    T.myAlias.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as ChildOf_RootElement_Name
FROM 
    @data.nodes('//root/*') AS T(myAlias)
;





ChildOf_RootElement_Name
--------------------------------------------------
table1
table2
```